# Nesting custom Blockly blocks into loops and generating the code

Tags: javascript, blockly

I am new to blockly and I am playing arround with creating custom blocks.

I've created a new file (move.js) in the blocks folder and there I created some custom blocks. All of them have similar structure, like the one below

```
Blockly.Blocks['move_forward'] = {
  init: function() {
    this.appendDummyInput()
        .appendField("Move Forward");
    this.appendDummyInput()
        .appendField(new Blockly.FieldImage("http://iosites.org/robotino/front.png", 20, 20, "Forward"));
    this.setInputsInline(true);
    this.setPreviousStatement(true, null);
    this.setNextStatement(true, null);
    this.setColour(120);
    this.setTooltip('');
    this.setHelpUrl('http://www.example.com/');
  }
};
```

Then I created a new file (move.js) in the generators/javascript folder and there I wrote very simple generators for the blocks (they only return a letter).

```
Blockly.JavaScript['move_forward'] = function(block) {
  return ['F;'];
};
```

The blocks work OK and return the text they are supposed to when stacked outside loops. But when I nest them inside a repeat or a while loop something happens and there is nothing returning. I have done some testing and I think that the problem occurs when the

```
Blockly.JavaScript.statementToCode
```

is called inside the repeat generator for my custom blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell, but the generators usually returns either

```
return code + '\n';
```

or

```
return [code, Blockly.JavaScript.ORDER_ATOMIC];
```

based on the block (if it returns something or just does something). You are generating (and returning) an array without the order (instead of just `return 'F;';`)... not sure, but maybe that is causing the problem.

Comment: Yes, removing the square brackets worked for me. Before that my code generated ok for single blocks, but when stacked, e.g. in a loop I'd get a line of commas at the end and a syntax error.